# Spyder 4.01 and plotly 4.5.1 - Anaconda attempts downgrade of Spyder

Tags: anaconda, plotly, spyder, plotly-dash

i am attempting to install plotly 4.5.1 using the anaconda environment - `conda install -c plotly plotly`.

However i can see from the terminal that Anaconda attempts to downgrade Spyder back to v 3.3.6. See attached picture:[image]

I would like to carry on using Spyder v4.0.1 but also need plotly. What is the best way to deal with this? I guess different anaconda environments, but then would that mean working in Spyder 3.3.6 to do my plotting?

PS: I also plan to install plotly-dash for dash board development. I suspect that this may also run into the same issue.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) We're trying to solve this problem with the Anaconda people right now. Hopefully it'll be fixed in the next days. In the meantime, please see [this issue](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/11550) for possible solutions.

Comment: Hi Carlos, thanks for the quick repsonse. What i can gather from the link is - install plotly and allow the downgrade of Spyder and follow that by updating to Spyder 4 again. Is that correct? I might try it in a cloned environment first, to see how things go. Where is the best place to keep track on the latest with this issue?

Comment: Yes, should try to install Spyder 4.0.1 again. And the best place is that issue.

Comment: It seems that something has changed recently. I installed plotly through Anaconda as normal, but downgrade of Spyder wasn't required.

Comment: Yeah, this was fixed by the Anaconda team three or four days ago.